# Bringing Chia seeds for personal consumption into Hawaii?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, hawaii

Can I bring chia seeds in my checked luggage to Hawaii for my personal consumption? The rules that I have read say that passion fruit and seeds are not allowed. This does not describe if it is only passion fruit seeds that are excluded.

---

It is likely that chia seeds are available to be purchased in Hawaii. Spending time searching for and buying anything in Hawaii is typically more expensive and takes away from snorkeling time. Since I already have a multi-component breakfast food mixed together with chia seeds it would be convenient to take this mixture with to Hawaii rather than spend hours reassembling while on vacation. It looks like raw seeds like chia seeds are not allowed to be taken into Hawaii.

Comment: From where to Hawaii? It may make a huge difference which country or even state you fly from.

Comment: Are they really not readily available to buy there?

Comment: Chia seeds are indeed widely available in Hawaii.

Comment: @user101209, it is no use to edit the deleted (non) answer, you need to edit the question if you want people to see the edit.

Comment: Can I get chia seeds delivered to my condo in Kauai  for less than $3 per pound?

Comment: Are the seeds sterile or viable?  That could make a big difference.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.

Comment: Chia seeds purchased at grocery stores or Walmart are viable seed, packaged for personal consumption. In Kauai the seeds are available for triple the cost and only 30 minutes away. Or for twice the cost at Walmart beatable hour drive away. The question was an economic one of having the seeds already purchased in Florida from Walmart and hoping to to conserve time and money and time. I was looking for an answer regarding the agricultural inspection required for entry , not to be questioned about my motivation.