# Can I fly internationally (US to Thailand) with edible chia seeds?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, food-and-drink

I like eating a spoonful of chia seeds as a nutritional supplement. Would I be able to fly internationally from the US to Thailand with a small plastic bag of chia seeds?

To be on the safe side, I assume I should declare these on the customs form.

I know that generally bringing plant seeds on international flights is a no-no. But haven't been able to find info for the situation where the seeds are really just food for personal consumption.

Worst case I suppose I could try finding them in Thailand or doing without them, but thought I'd at least look into bringing my own.

Tried searching around on this topic, but got a lot of false positives. Closest I could find was [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143470/bringing-chia-seeds-for-personal-consumption-into-hawaii).

Comment: A quick search for "chia seeds thailand" suggests that chia seeds are readily available in Thailand.

Comment: Why do you think that food for personal consumption is not subject to a country's agricultural import controls?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I think that food _is_ subject to a country's import controls. That is why I am asking, and why I assumed that I'd have to declare it on the customs forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Thai Customs authority, [food is a restricted good which requires a permit to bring into Thailand](https://www.customs.go.th/cont_strc_simple.php?ini_content=individual_160426_01&lang=en&left_menu=menu_individual_submenu_03_01) and [you must declare it by going through the "red lane" at customs](https://www.customs.go.th/list_strc_simple_neted.php?ini_content=individual_160503_03_160905_01&lang=en&left_menu=menu_individual_submenu_01_160421_01).

However, [many travelers report](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293916-i3687-k6224148-Can_you_take_prepackaged_foods_into_Thailand-Bangkok.html) that it is not a problem in practice to bring small amounts of prepackaged food clearly for personal consumption. It depends on your tolerance for risk weighed against how desperately you want to have these specific seeds with you.

Note that many delicious snacks are readily and cheaply available in Thailand; you can probably find chia for sale there, but even if you have trouble with that, I'm sure you'll find *something* you want to eat.

Comment: Keep in mind that that assumes the packages are sealed, not opened for use! And that they are commercial packages (so store bought, factory packaged, not something you put in a baggy yourself and taped shut).